# logic to select the zip file from source and sending it to another directory

Tags: java

I am stuck up in an odd situation that ia I have a folder in C: named sourceconsists of one .dat file and one .zip file
now I want to move only zip file to another diretory in c : named target

1)  Now first I have to write the logic to pick up the .zip file from source folder

what I HAVE TRIED IS ...

```
private void filemove(String FilePath2, String s2) {  filepath2 contains the location of source c:\\source

String destination ="C:\\target\\"

        try {
            File f = new File(FilePath2);

            if (f.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {

//please advise the logic to copy the file to destination folder


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

please advise the logic to copy the files to destination folder

Answer (score 1):

[`FileUtils#copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) from [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) should suit your needs.

Comment: @spoom could you please update the code as well that will be a great help

Comment: @KumarMadan Create a `File` instance that targets the destination dir, and use the above method with `f` and the `File` instance you created as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Create another file object with the current file  `path`.

And Use the method [renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) in File class and give the `destination path` to it.

public boolean renameTo(File dest);

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.

Comment: @suresh thanks a lot could you please update the code as I have done , if possible then reformat mine one that will be a great help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely trying yourself would benefit you far better. S.O. is here to teach you to fish, not to catch them for you. There's 2 good answers there. If you want your code written for you there's sites where you can pay someone to write it for you at a reasonable price. Rent a coder is one.

Answer (score 0):

The best wayto copy a file in java is using the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)
Look at the class FileUtils it has a lot of methods for copying files.

For example copyFileToDirectory :

```
File srcFile = new File("c:\test.dat");
File dstDir = new File("c:\targetdir\");
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, dstDir);
```